# Merge Two Link List in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Merge two sorted linked lists and return it as a new list. The new list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.

I have it almost complete. I cant get it to work. Any hints to make it work will be appreciated.

```
class node():
    def __init__(self, data, next_node):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_node

    def set_next(self, new_node):
        self.next_node = new_node

class LinkList(object):

    def __init__(self, head = None):
        self.head = head

    def add(self, data):
        new_node = node(data)
        new_node.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = new_node

    def printlist(self):
        current_node = self.head
        while (current_node != None):
            print(current_node.get_data(), end="->")
            current_node = current_node.get_next()


def merge(L1, L2):

    temp = None

    if L1 is None:
        return L2

    if L2 is None:
        return L1

    if L1.data <= L2.data:
        temp = L1
        temp.next_node = merge(L1.next_node, L2)

    else:
        temp = L2
        temp.next_node = merge(L1,L2.next_node)

        return temp


def main():

    list1 = LinkList()
    list1.add(10)
    list1.add(20)
    list1.add(30)

    list2 = LinkList()
    list2.add(10)
    list2.add(30)
    list2.add(50)

    list3 = LinkList()

    list3.head = merge(list1.head, list2.head)
    print("merge link list: ", end=" " )
    list3.printlist()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Which part isn't working? What exactly is your error?

Comment: 1. in add function, I get type error :__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'next_node'.

Comment: I don't know if you're doing this for a class assignment, or whatever.  But, I got asked how to make a linked list in python during a Google interview... and I just think this is a tremendous waste of time.  Python has lists built in, and you *should not* "roll your own".  Especially since python does not have pointers, there is *absolutely no reason* to implement a linked list in python, and ZERO educational benefit.

Answer (score 0):

you only pass data argument,so set the next_node default value None

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, data, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = None
```

below is the ascending sorted solution

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def __str__(self):
        return "<Node>{}</Node> {}".format(self.data, self.next)


class LinkList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.current = self.head = None

    def add(self, node):
        if not self.head:
            self.head = self.current = node
        else:
            self.current.next = node
            self.current = node

    def __str__(self):
        return "<head>{}</head> {}".format(self.head.data, self.head.next)


def merge(lst1, lst2):
    rtn = LinkList()
    while lst1 and lst2:
        if lst1.data < lst2.data:
            rtn.add(Node(lst1.data))
            lst1 = lst1.next
        else:
            rtn.add(Node(lst2.data))
            lst2 = lst2.next
    if lst1:
        rtn.add(lst1)
    if lst2:
        rtn.add(lst2)
    return rtn


def main():
    lst = LinkList()
    lst.add(Node(1))
    lst.add(Node(2))
    lst.add(Node(3))
    lst2 = LinkList()
    lst2.add(Node(1.1))
    lst2.add(Node(2.1))
    lst2.add(Node(3.1))
    rtn = merge(lst.head, lst2.head)
    print(rtn)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Since `self.next_node` is being explicitly set to `None` in the function body anyway, there's no reason for `next_node` to even be in the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding to the head of the list:

```
def add(self, data):
    new_node = node(data)
    new_node.set_next(self.head)
    self.head = new_node
```

That means your list is reversed. Therefore you have to do a reverse check during the merge:

```
if L1.data >= L2.data:
```

full text:

```
class node():
    def __init__(self, data, next_node = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_node

    def set_next(self, new_node):
        self.next_node = new_node

class LinkList(object):

    def __init__(self, head = None):
        self.head = head

    def add(self, data):
        new_node = node(data)
        new_node.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = new_node

    def printlist(self):
        current_node = self.head
        while (current_node != None):
            print (current_node.get_data(), end = "->")
            current_node = current_node.get_next()
        print ()

def merge(L1, L2):

    temp = None

    if L1 is None:
        return L2

    if L2 is None:
        return L1
    if L1.data >= L2.data:
        temp = L1
        temp.next_node = merge(L1.next_node, L2)
    else:
        temp = L2
        temp.next_node = merge(L1, L2.next_node)

    return temp


def main():

    list1 = LinkList()
    list1.add(10)
    list1.add(20)
    list1.add(30)

    print("list2: ", end=" " )
    list1.printlist()

    list2 = LinkList()
    list2.add(11)
    list2.add(21)
    list2.add(51)
    print("list2: ", end=" " )
    list2.printlist()

    list3 = LinkList()

    list3.head = merge(list1.head, list2.head)
    print("merge link list: ", end=" " )
    list3.printlist()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Currently it gives output in descending order. How can i get it in ascending order.